# How to send Properties file in src/test data to src/main application in Unit Testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

Hi I am new to Java and Spring boot.

I have a little project in which I have a main class under `src/main/java/MainApp.java`
and properties are `src/main/resources/application.properties`.

When i read the `src/main/resouces/application.properties` from `MainApp.java` it works fine.

Similarly i have `src/test/java/MainAppTest.java` and `src/test/resources/application.properties`.

When i read `src/test/resouces/application.properties` from `MainAppTest.java` it works fine.

Problem: I want to test a method in the `MainApp.java` which uses a property to create a file in a particular directory. When i call that method from `MainAppTest.java` the property can be read from `src/test/resources` but when the program execution goes to `MainApp.java` it shows that properties are `null`.

**How to transfer the properties read from `src/test/resources` to `src/main/java/MainApp.java`**

Code:

MainApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
@EnableScheduling
public class EquensfilemqApplication {

@Value("${dir.location}")
private String directoryLocation;

protected void processMessage(String message)
    {
        String fileName = "first.txt";
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter (directoryLocation + fileName);
        
        // shows null when test is executed
        System.out.println("dir in main: " + directoryLocation);
        
        writer.write (message);
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

MainAppTest.java

```
class EquensfilemqApplicationTests {
    @Value("${dir.location}")
    private String directoryLocation;
    
    @Test
    void processMessageTest() {
        String testMessage = "test content...";
        
        // prints correct value when test is executed
        System.out.println("dir in test: " + directoryLocation);

        MainApp app = new MainApp();
        app.processMessage(testMessage);
        
    }
}
```

I am not aware of any methods/ways by which we can achieve this.

Comment: Is the `MainAppTest.java` code example complete? I do not see that you are using `@RunWith`/`@ExtendWith`.

Comment: If you're creating `MainApp` using the constructor, how can you hope for any properties to be injected into the instance?

Comment: You are trying to use `@Value` before Spring initialization. Spring needs to initialize itself and add all autowired Beans to its container (your main class included). The `@Value` annotation like the `@Autowired` annotation, both they require the class to be a Bean itself.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I see @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) cannot be resolved to a type so i removed it from test class

Comment: @Mugiwara What do you suggest should be done to allow spring to initialize itself with the bean of main class.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this problem using the ReflectionUtils in JUnit

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(objectOfMainApplication, "variableNameInMainApplication", variableNameInTestClass);
```